# Accessing UITableViewController from another ViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

My question may sound very basic but I want to know the best and simplest way to access a UITableViewController and its tableView and properties, from another view controller. Many Thanks....

Comment: show your use-case.

Comment: Well, I have a viewController and a tableViewController linked to it and I want to make some changes on my tableView and its Cells from main viewController. I hope this helped enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set UITableViewController instance as a variable of a new view controller.

e.g.,

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
func launch() {
let vc2 = VC2()
vc2.previousVC = self
present(vc2,..)
}
}

claass VC2: UIViewController {
weak var previousVC: VC1?
}
```

you can do the same setup if you use segues:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SomeSegue" {
        if let vc2 = segue.destination as? VC2 {
                vc2.previousVC = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i access tableView?!
You mean define an instance of tableView with :

class TBC: MyTableViewController {
}

If so, how can i access tableView?

Comment: In fact, I want to call tableView.reloadData() from my main viewController

Comment: @Alireza previousVC.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Awesome! I got it!

Comment: ticked and accomplished!

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use reactive/asnychronous approach for this. For asnychronous approach you could use notificaiton center (there are many other approaches). In your first controller, where you have tableView add this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveNotification(_:)), name: .didReceiveNotification, object: nil)
@objc func onDidReceiveNotification(_ notification:Notification) {
    // Do something now with your UITableView   
}
```

In your second controller that needs to change or do something with your first view controller and its tableView you post your notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didReceiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Also you could use your reactive approach using RxSwift and RxCocoa and create observable and observe its values in onNext() event.
You could create subject like this in your first view controller:

```
let subject = PublishSubject<String>()
let subscriptionOne = subject.subscribe(onNext: { string in
    // Do something now with your UITableView. You can pass your custom model instead of string
    print("First Subscription: ", string)                     
})
```

Now in the second view controller you can call onNext() method after yo do some work, like this:

```
subject.onNext("3")
```

Comment: @ Kenan Begic Thank you. sounds like a complicated approach :)

Comment: Actually it is not when you get used to and it is very simple when you get the concept :)

Comment: I agree buddy ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way by far is to bind it to a global variable.

Make a global variable set equal to UITableViewController() like 
`var tableVC = UITableViewController()`

Then in the viedDidLoad() function, type `tableVC = self` to set it equal to the current view controller.

From there just do `tableVC.(insert variable/method here)` to change things easily.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.